# How to call JavaScript function with parameter from a loop in .cshtml(Razor) page?

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a loop in my `cshtml` view:

```
@foreach (var ph in Model.Item2)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@ph.Id</td>
        <td>@ph.Name</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="rounded-button rounded-button-blue" value="@Resources.Language.edit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "PublishingHouse", new { Id = @ph.Id })'" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="remove" class="rounded-button rounded-button-blue" value="@Resources.Language.delete" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Remove", "PublishingHouse", new { Id = @ph.Id })'"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I want to call a JavaScript function which will show bootbox.Confirm/Alert window and then call controller method. I tried many different methods but after clicking button nothing happened or button was just disappearing.

I tried the following among other things:

**Try 1:**

```
onclick="remove(this)" data-assigned-id="@ph.Id"

<script type="text/javascript">
    function remove(elem)
    {
        var id = $(elem).data('assigned-id');
        bootbox.alert("Deleting");
    }
</script>
```

**Try 2:**

```
onclick="@remove('"+ph.Id+"')")"

function remove(phId)
{
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Publishing House" + phId, function(result)
    {
        if (result == true)
            bootbox.alert("Usuwam");
    });
}
```

**Try 3:**

```
onclick="@("remove('"+ph.Id+"')")"
```

Comment: first thing is that its not good to write inline javascripts inside html. add a class for each element and bind click event to that element .

Comment: can you post the `HTML` code generated by the `CSHTML` ?